# How to ensure that JavaFX is installed (espacially on Ubuntu)?

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, javafx-8, openjfx

I want to write my first JavaFX 8 application (doing my first experiments with e(fx)clipse, etc.) and have a few concerns about platform independence.

JavaFX 8 is a part of the Oracle JRE, which is the most used JRE on Windows. Therefore, I do not really bother here, since JavaFX will be installed on nearly every Windows machine running Java 8.

But on Ubuntu and other *nix, OpenJDK is often used as Java distribution. Since `openjfx` is separated from `open-jdk-8-*`, many will not have JavaFX installed by default.

I thought of:

- Writing an install script that calls `sudo apt-get install openjfx` (which I would like to avoid, since I would like the executable .jar to be runable on its own, without script)
- Shipping a JavaFX distribution (i.e., its .jars) with my applications (but I read that this should not be done)

Both ideas do not seem very promising...

Since I hope that there are some JavaFX pros out there, i hope that someone can help me with *"What are the best possibilities to ensure that my JavaFX application will run fine, both on Windows and Ubuntu?"* What are state-of-the-art techniques on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Also consider [tag:java-web-start].

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for the hint, I will have a look at it!

Comment: The JDK also ships with tools for building "Self-contained application bundles", which essentially bundle the JDK, JavaFX, and your application into a native installable app. The [deployment guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/) has details on how to do this.

Comment: @James_D Thank you! I found the link after I posted the question. The problem with self-contained application bundles is that you need one for every platform (e.g., "a windows build", "a ubuntu build", etc.). This blows up the whole build process. I still hope to find a way to get around that.

Comment: @MarkusWeninger how do you think about distributing your application? with an installer or just as some ZIP-file containing your jars? How about putting this "JDK needs to be installed with javafx" inside some install-instructions?

Comment: Just some additional thought: the distribution/subsetting of the JDK is restricted http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jre-8-readme-2095710.html

Comment: @FibreFoX We planned (or would prefer) to ship our application as zipped jars ("download and run"-approach). Yes, I think we will end up with a mix of install instructions and an install script for Ubuntu (which runs `sudo apt-get install openjfx`). There would also be the possibility to build an OpenJFX build (https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX) and to ship that one, but I think this is over the top for this project. I think we stay with install instructions+install script and hope that OpenJFX someday will be automatically installed alongside OpenJDK.

Comment: @MarkusWeninger so your approach is only valid for Linux/Ubuntu? It is possible to create an installer with `javapackager` (or javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-gradle-plugin ... I'm the maintainer/creator of them) without the bundled JRE and adjusted control-file, which is used for creating the DEB-installer. All you need is to adjust/add `Depends` for some openjfx. You might need to adjust the postinst-script too for setting the path to RUNTIME, like here: https://github.com/VocabHunter/VocabHunter/pull/17/files

Comment: @FibreFoX Since most of the windows Java installations will have JavaFX installed, my main concern is Linux/Ubuntu, yes. I have to admit that I am not very experienced with installers, but I will have a look at it, thank you! Creating a DEB-installer with a dependency on `openjdk` and `openjfx` sounds like a good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page (http://www.sj-vs.net/creating-a-simple-debian-deb-package-based-on-a-directory-structure/) describes very well how to build a simple .deb package based on any directory structure (e.g., with precompiled stuff).
You can than add your dependencies, e.g., to javafx packages, to the `Depends` section of the `control` file. (https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html). This forces any installer like `apt` or `dpkg` to install javafx together with your package and makes them fail if this package is not available. You can also add a `postinst` script that will be executed after the installation in which you can set classpaths etc if necessary.